# How does CUDA handle thread offset as in OpenCL?

Tags: cuda, opencl, offset

For example, I can launch kernels with offsets on thread ids in OpenCL so when using multiple GPUs, second GPU threads can directly start from an arbitrary integer value:

```
GPU1: thread idx 0 to k
GPU2: thread idx k+1 to N
```

and kernel can look exactly same for all GPUs:

```
__kernel(..)
{
   int threadId=get_global_id(0); // this starts from k+1 for GPU2
   ..
}
```

What is equivalent of this in CUDA when calling kernels in **driver API**?

OpenCL has

```
cl_int clEnqueueNDRangeKernel ( cl_command_queue command_queue,
    cl_kernel kernel,
    cl_uint work_dim,
    const size_t *global_work_offset, // this can be given k+1
    const size_t *global_work_size,
    const size_t *local_work_size,
    cl_uint num_events_in_wait_list,
    const cl_event *event_wait_list,
    cl_event *event)
```

Do I have to embed the offset in kernel myself such as below example to use most similarly looking kernel on multipe GPUs?

```
__global__ void vecAdd(.., int * gpuParams)
{
    int offset=gpuParams[0];
    int threadId = offset + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
}
```

(this is for flattened buffer accesses and kernels)

This offset will be changed dynamically before each kernel launch so I can't use #define for it I guess.

Cuda driver api has this for launching kernel:

```
CUresult cuLaunchKernel ( CUfunction f, unsigned int  gridDimX, 
                unsigned int  gridDimY, unsigned int  gridDimZ, 
                unsigned int  blockDimX, unsigned int  blockDimY, 
                unsigned int  blockDimZ, unsigned int  sharedMemBytes, 
                CUstream hStream, void** kernelParams, void** extra )
```

Comment: I know CUDA isn't OpenCL but Nvidia does run OpenCL and works with its thread offset, do I need to do what Nvidia does in background? Is it something on the hacking level? I can use grid as an offset for multiple of blocks size but how can I add thread-offset in first block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent functionality in CUDA for this, but you don't really need it either.

In the standard CUDA model you cannot launch kernels on multiple devices with a single API call (and you technically can't allocate memory on multiple devices with a single API call either). Each GPU is effectively independent.

NVIDIA have introduced a multi-device launch and synchronization approach as part of the new [cooperative groups](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/in) features in CUDA 9, but these are entirely different from what you are asking about.

Comment: I'm working with CUDA 8.0 first update but I'll check it, I remember I saw it before but thought it was only for dual-gpu graphics cards.

Comment: Found that `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` can do an implicit offset array initialization without resorting to parameters of kernel and kernel looks identical for all gpus with addition of implementation of `get_global_cuda_offset(dimension)` function.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik You don't need that either. Any CUDA pointer type supports arithmetic. You can add offsets directly to any pointer, and pass that offset to a kernel. The only time you can't do that is with symbols, which is why that API call has an offset.

Comment: You are right about it is easier but what if all gpus also need to access element 1,2,3,4,5(read) of same array and also their own ranges(write)(after their own offsets)? Then this pointer trick would make 1,2,3,4,5 unreachable? An example could be nbody algorithm all-pairs(but without writing). My intention is to have exact same cuda kernel string for all devices.(but automatic addition of some definitions before that kernel are ok)